# Call all setters

Tags: java

I want to call a method `setDirty` when calling any setter of a class.
Is there an easy way to achieve this in Java without requiring code duplication (calling `setDirty` on every setter)?

If this is a stupid question, I'll gladly delete it, but I can't seem to find a quick answer.

Comment: Why you don't want  to insert "setDirty" on each of other set methods?

Comment: I think explicitly writing out `setDirty` in all the setters is the correct thing to do. Otherwise it isn't clear to a person reading your code that `setDirty` is being called every time a setter is being invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a stupid question, but no easy way to achieve it in plain Java. With AspectJ or a Groovy AST transform you could automatically insert the call into each setter, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for you, using Java reflection.

Read this question: [Capture method calls in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4794695/capture-method-calls-in-java)

Using [Dynamic proxy class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/reflection/proxy.html) you can proxy the class where the setters are and then fire setDirty when your set methods are invoked.

```
public interface A { void m(); }

public class AImpl implements A { public void m() {} }

public class EnqueueProxy implements java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler {

    private Object obj;
    private Method method_setDirty = null;

    public static Object newInstance(Object obj) {

        if( null==method_setDirty ){
            // Gets setDirty method 
            Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
            int ms_length = methods.length;
            for (int i = 0; i < ms_length; i++){
                if("setDirty".equals(methods[i].getName()) ){
                    method_setDirty = methods[i];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(
            obj.getClass().getClassLoader(),
            obj.getClass().getInterfaces(),
            new EnqueueProxy(obj));
    }

    private EnqueueProxy(Object obj) {
        this.obj = obj;
    }

    public Object invoke(Object proxy, Method m, Object[] args) throws Throwable {
        try {
            new MethodInvocation(obj, m, args);
            if( "set".equals(m.getName().substring(0,3)) ){
                new MethodInvocation(obj, method_setDirty, args);
            }
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            throw e.getTargetException();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("unexpected invocation exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now You can call your class with this:

```
A a = (A) EnqueueProxy.newInstance(new AImpl());
a.setSomething();
```